# If I wrap my whole application with @autoreleasepool can I ignore pointers?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I were to wrap my UIApplicationMain in an `@autoreleasepool`would it mean I would never have to think about memory management in objective C?

For example:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([DDAppDelegate class]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most UIApplicationMains are already wrapped in an @autorelease pool. You still need to think about memory management, less if you're using Automatic Reference Counting.

Answer (score 0):

You `main` is always wrapped in an autorelease pool:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Since this is need to register object to be autoreleased. If you are using `ARC` then this will also work for none autorelease object.

It will never be that you do not have to think about memory management. Since ARC will only follow you code, thus is you make a `static strong` variable it will not be released since you told the compiler to keep it around. Just take in account the deceleration of variables and use `ARC` you will less issues with memory management.

If you are using any CoreFoundation classes, you will have to do all the memory management your self, since `ARC` will not do memory management for CoreFoundation classes.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get to know bases of memory management in obj-c. For example

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2657/

http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/memory-management.html

@autoreleasepool just helps to manage memory in cases when lots of autoreleased objects are created, and it will be expensive to keep them all till app's runloop finish.